# Jmeter sampler does not see resources file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jmeter

I am creating custom sampler for JMeter. I am able to import my jar into library, the sampler is visible within the GUI, but the fields are not displayed properly.

[image: Project structure]

Here is my code.

Custom.java

```
public class Custom extends AbstractSampler implements TestBean {

  private String email = "";

  public Custom() {
    super();
  }

  public SampleResult sample(Entry entry) {
    SampleResult res = new SampleResult();
    res.setSampleLabel(getName());
    res.setResponseData(("Hello " + getEmail()).getBytes());
    res.setSuccessful(Boolean.TRUE);
    return res;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email){ this.email = email; }
  public String getEmail(){ return email; }
}
```

CustomBeanInfo.java

```
public class CustomBeanInfo extends BeanInfoSupport {

  protected CustomBeanInfo() {
    super(Custom.class);

    createPropertyGroup("contact", new String[]{
      "email"
    });

    PropertyDescriptor p = property("email");
    p.setValue(NOT_UNDEFINED, Boolean.TRUE);
    p.setValue(DEFAULT, "asd");
  }
}
```

CustomResources.properties

```
displayName=Custom Sampler
email.displayName=Email Address
email.shortDescription=User Email Address
contact.displayName=Contact
```

And this is how it looks in JMeter GUI. My guess is that the properties file is not correctly attached to sampler or the constructor is not executed.

[image: JMeter Gui]

**EDIT 1**: Added pom.xml file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
  <artifactId>custom-sampler</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
      <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
      <version>2.10</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
</project>
```

**EDIT 2**: When using sampler (adding it to thread group) following error appears in log

```
2016/03/25 09:28:23 WARN  - jmeter.testbeans.gui.GenericTestBeanCustomizer: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.Custom#email(java.lang.String) does not appear to have been configured
```

Comment: do you really need Beans / resources? Generally you don't have to have them: if you look at jmeter-plugins.org, or even JMeter's own samplers, most of them do not use beans and resources.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the modifier of the constructor

```
protected CustomBeanInfo() {
```

must be

```
public CustomBeanInfo() {
```

don't ask why com/sun/beans/finder/InstanceFinder.class catch the exception without message :

```
protected T instantiate(Class<?> var1, String var2) {
    if (var1 != null) {// 90
        try {
            if (var2 != null) {// 92
                var1 = ClassFinder.findClass(var2, var1.getClassLoader());// 93
            }

            if (this.type.isAssignableFrom(var1)) {// 95
                return var1.newInstance();// 96
            }
        } catch (Exception var4) {// 99
            ;
        }
    }

    return null;// 103
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Probably wrong. See comments.

I think you've just misnamed the properties file. The [JavaDoc for BeanInfoSupport](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testbeans/BeanInfoSupport.html) reads:

> Even before any such modifications, a resource bundle named
>   xxxResources (where xxx is the **fully qualified** bean class name) will
>   be obtained if available and used to localize the following:

It says the filename must be fully qualified. Digging around the source code for an example I couldn't find a good one, but I did find this file, [notes_on_extending.txt](https://github.com/udomsak/JMeter/blob/43f22519f0a09fbf17e8e13186a106d7134a6292/xdocs/extending/notes_on_extending.txt):

> 1. Pick a package and make three files:
>
>    - [ComponentName].java (org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet.java)
>    - [ComponentName]BeanInfo.java (org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSetBeanInfo.java)
>    - **[ComponentName]Resources.properties (org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSetResources.properties)**

I think your properties file must be named `org.apache.jmeter.custom.CustomResources.properties`.

Comment: I think I'm wrong. I found some examples in the [official repo mirror](https://github.com/apache/jmeter) (e.g. [KeystoreConfig.properties](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/components/org/apache/jmeter/config/KeystoreConfigResources.properties)), and they've named the properties file as you have. I'll leave my answer here so others don't go down this path if they try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I solve putting *Resource.properties in same package of BeanInfo.java

IE:

```
src
|-main
  |-java
    |-org.apache.jmeter.custom
      |-Custom.java
      |-CustomBeanInfo.java
      |-CustomResource.properties
```

Make this test: Open your jar with winrar (or other tools) and move properties file

NB: When you build project, resources won't put in java packages, for example in maven you have to specify which file keep in package